# Bigbluebutton installation guide for ubuntu 12.04

Tags: bigbluebutton

I am getting error like "E: Unable to locate package bigbluebutton
".I need proper guide for installing bigbluebutton on ubuntu 12.04.And also I followed many links.which shows same error like. So,please help me.

Comment: The latest version of BigBlueButton supports installation on Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit.  See: http://docs.bigbluebutton.org/install/install.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am the product manager for BigBlueButton.

You can expect full support for Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit as part of the next release of BigBlueButton (after 0.81).

Answer (score 1):

We faced similar issue couple of day back 
after doing **"sudo apt-get update"** we are able to proceed with installation.

hope this works.